# Php echo html. Use newline, \n, or not?

Tags: php, html

Is there any difference on this:

```
echo "</body>\n</html>";
```

and

```
echo "</body></html>";
```

I wonder if the 'newline' has any affect on browser.

Comment: It doesn't have any effect. You could have tested it by yourself...

Comment: No it doesn't ...

Comment: Use <br/> instead of  \n in echo.

Comment: Ok. I know that if I wanted a visual effect I should use the html-element <br />. The reason I asked the question was because I saw an example  were they used newline. And I thought why...? To have a better structured source-code, or is it some kind of browser compatibility thing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `\n` does have effect on the output of your HTML. As you can see [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51242f5aa2eef7d8a15ca30fe34ae4d58d535828).

```
echo "</body>\n</html>";
```

outputs your HTML as:

```
</body>
</html>
```

while

```
echo "</body></html>";
```

outputs your HTML as

```
</body></html>
```

Comment: Are you sure about what you are telling to us and the relation to OPs question?

Comment: Tested in both Chrome and Firefox. And you can see the result in the link I provided.

Comment: Please take a look at the other answers here! We all know that \n leads to  a new line.

Answer (score 1):

The "\n" doesn't have any effect on the displayed html on the browser. If you want to go to the next line, echo a `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

The

```
 echo "</body>\n</html>";
```

have no echo in browser  but you can see th effect in source code (the \n is not an html element and is not processed  by browser

```
so you can see an effect in the code generated  page (crtl+U)  as  

 </body>
 </html>
```

if you need  an effect in browser  you should use a proper tag  as `<br />`

```
  echo "</body><br /></html>";  // in this case poorly useful do the fact add a new line between a not (normally useful part
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in your case. However, newline leads to anonymous text block insertion in case it is between two inline (or inline-block) elements:

```html
<h2>Newline</h2>
<p>
<span>first</span>
<span>second</span>
</p>
<h2>No newline</h2>
<p>
  <span>first</span><span>second</span>
</p>
<h2>newline in comment</h2>
<p>
  <span>first</span><!--
  --><span>second</span>
</p>
```

There're some techniques to avoid these blocks, like inserting comments or setting `font-size: 0` for container element.

Lotta details might be found in the [article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).